# iOS 10 Notification Content Extension not loading

Tags: swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10, unnotificationrequest

I have a bare-bones app to play with push notifications. I have the Notification Service Extension working. I can send a remote notification with an image URL and have it load.

I can't seem to get Notification Content Extension working. I've gone through multiple tutorials and they all say, just create a Notification Content Extension from the target menu and then inside the Notification Content Extensions Info.plist set the

```
UNNotificationCategory
```

to some string. Then when you push the notification, inside the "aps" json-block make sure to have category the same as UNNotificationCategory.

When I receive a notification, I try to swipe it down, left or right and nothing really happens.  However, the service extension is working great.

I am using an iPhone 5 with ios 10 and XCode 8.0. I read that at one point only devices with 3d touch could view the content extension but that has since changed since xCode 8 is out of beta.

Any ideas? How can I go about debugging this? I've tried running the app with the Notification Extension selected and printing out stuff inside

```
didReceive
```

but am not having any luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what I read elsewhere on stackoverflow and online, expanding the push notification did not work on an iPhone 5 and IOS 10. I borrowed an iPhone 6+ and my code worked fine.

Comment: If you believe you are seeing a bug, or the documentation is lacking, make sure to open a bug report with Apple at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I have been testing it on 5s and 6 and the extensions have been working absolutely fine.

Comment: I have iPhone 5s but not working. Guys Help me . any idea. UNNotificationExtensionCategory is same as APN and "mutable_content" : true

Answer (score 42):

Make sure to set the **Extension's deployment target** to the same as your Application target.

[image]

Comment: You saved hours of debugging. Thanks

Comment: That's why I was on working on iOS 12 device, You made my day

Comment: Spent a good deal of time before figuring out why one extension is working and the other one isn't, only to find out I had forgotten to set the deployment target. Thanks.

Comment: I just LOVE you.

Comment: So after fixing the deployment target, I also had to restart the device to get this to work.  Not even deleting the application worked until I restarted my phone.  Wow.  Thanks Apple for making this easy. :(

Comment: You made my day, dude! So helpful! THanks

Answer (score 7):

Please check if you set the category identifier in your `UNMutableNotificationContent()` For e.g.

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.categoryIdentifier = "awesomeNotification"
```

where "awesomeNotification" is the identifier for your `UNNotificationCategory`

Comment: I am doing this with a remote notification, but I've made sure to set the "category" field equal to the UNNotificationCategory inside the "aps" field

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works perfectly. So yes, don't forget to have the field "category" inside the "aps" node in the received push notification :-)

Answer (score 5):

Such problem. iOS Content Extension work fine with iPhone 5s, SE, iPad2mini, but doesn't work with iPhoine 5, 5c:

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().supportsContentExtensions is false on iPhoine 5, 5c

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please note that this answer is not very helpful, especially since the question already has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was due to changing signing certificates. I was able to resolve it by:

1. Deleting the app (and all apps in app group)
2. Restarting phone
3. Quitting Xcode
4. Cleaning project
5. Running again